# How to upload a simple image from a mobile device using expo image picker to AWS S3?

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, expo

I use Expo with react native and I am really stuck on this ... expo doesn't support firebase cloud storage which I have been using for ages to upload my images. So I am left with AWS S3 which I have never worked with. I already found this example on github: https://github.com/expo/image-upload-example/
but I couldn't get the grasp of what is the backend part about and what is apiURl that is used ... I apologize I haven't provide any code attempt but I am totally lost and I can't really see through the huge amount of bla bla bla documentation on AWS.

I have made it in the AWS S3 console so that the bucket I have created is accessed publicly. I have no problem for that. I don't need the user to be authed to upload images and any other restrictions just need to accomplish a simple upload.

So if anyone can help me through the code for this one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Expo specifically, but I have setup my RN project to be able to upload to s3. Given the example you posted, it is fairly similar to what I ended up doing.

So obviously the first thing you need to do is go setup a bucket on AWS S3. From within the AWS console you should be able to find your specific access key and access secret, you will need both of those along with your bucket name.

The idea behind the example you posted, and what I ended up doing is to have a controlled server where you can safely use the access key and secret to create a unique "signed" url that can be used to upload the image directly into your bucket.  You don't want to do this on your client b/c having a secret on your client is just asking to get hacked.  Assume nothing on the client is ever completely secure.

I was already building a node server as the backend to my application so I had this part already up and running.  If you are new to creating a backend server, I would suggest looking up how to setup an Express server [here](https://expressjs.com). You can host the app for free (with limitations) on a service such as [heroku](http://heroku.com).  There is even a great article covering this whole process in a bit more detail [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node).  Basically you create a an app with a distinct `GET` route that can be hit by your client app.  That route will accept a query parameter with the file name of the file that is going to be uploaded.  You should use the [official aws sdk](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) which will take your access key, secret, bucket name, and the file name then generate a unique url that will be sent back down to your client app.

Essentially what your client app will do is prepare the file needing to be uploaded.  You should have the file name of the file ready and then you send a `GET` request to the url route you just setup on your Express app. When you get a response back from your server it should contain that unique url.  I then used [react native fetch blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) library to perform a `PUT` request to that unique url you just received. If all goes well it *should* upload the file directly to that bucket securely. Make sure you set the `Content-Type` in the header to the type of file you are uploading.

I know this isn't a bunch of code that will do the upload, but it should help you understand what is needed and get you heading in the right direction.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. You really helped me understand the mechanism of all this ... and I think I now clearly understand what the gentleman who provided the example in the link I mentioned exactly was doing ... Thank you very much and sorry you had to go through all this typing :)

Comment: glad it helped!

Comment: Hi, if you don’t mind using cloudinary, I show how to upload and then get the uploaded url to save to firebase
https://medium.com/@ifeoluwaking24/how-to-upload-an-image-in-expo-react-native-to-firebase-using-cloudinary-24aac981c87

Also you can try it snack but make sure you add your cloud_name and upload_preset
https://snack.expo.io/@ifeking/upload-to-cloudinary

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a long time. This is what I did.

Make sure you follow the amplify guide for setting up a app. `amplify init`, `amplify add auth`, `amplify push`, and then `amplify add storage` and then do this.

````
import Amplify, { Storage } from 'aws-amplify'
import config from './src/aws-exports'
// import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
// Might need to switch line 7 to awsconfig 
Amplify.configure(config)

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
  const [name, setName] = useState('Evan Erickson')

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
        const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    
    console.log(result) 

    async function pathToImageFile(data) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(data);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        await Storage.put(`customers/${name}`, blob, {
          contentType: 'image/jpeg', // contentType is optional
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error uploading file:', err);
      }
    }
    // later
    pathToImageFile(result.uri);
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
      <Button title="Upload image" onPress={() => {alert(image)}} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default withAuthenticator(App)```
````